# Why is entity framework trying to delete the associated row on delete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I've got this code:

```cs
...
     modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(builder => {
           builder.ToTable("person");
           builder.Property(x => x.PersonId).HasColumnName("nconst");
           builder.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasColumnName("firstname");
           builder.Property(x => x.LastName).HasColumnName("lastname");
           builder.Property(x => x.BirthYear).HasColumnName("birthyear");
           builder.HasKey(x => x.PersonId);
           builder.HasMany(x => x.Works).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
           builder.HasOne(x => x.Death).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Death>(x => x.PersonId);
     });

     modelBuilder.Entity<PersonBookmark>(builder => {
          builder.ToTable("personbookmark");
          builder.Property(x => x.PersonId).HasColumnName("nconst");
          builder.Property(x => x.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");
          builder.Property(x => x.Date).HasColumnName("date");
          builder.Property(x => x.Label).HasColumnName("label");
          builder.HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.PersonId });
          builder.HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.PersonBookmarks).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
          builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey<PersonBookmark>(x => x.PersonId).HasForeignKey<Person>(x => x.PersonId);
     });
...
```

```cs
namespace DataService.Domain {

    public class PersonBookmark {

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace DataService.Domain {

    public class Person {

        public Person() {
            Works = new HashSet<Work>();
        }

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string BirthYear { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Death Death { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
public bool DeletePersonBookmark(int UserId, string PersonId) {
    var personBookmark = Context.PersonBookmarks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == UserId && x.PersonId == PersonId);
     var found = personBookmark != null;

     if (found) {
          Context.PersonBookmarks.Remove(personBookmark);
          Context.SaveChanges();
     }

     return found;
}
```

and when I'm trying to remove a `PersonBookmark` from the database, I've got this Exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---- Npgsql.PostgresException : 23503: update or delete on table "person" violates foreign key constraint "personbookmark_nconst_fkey" on table "personbookmark"
```

It looks like entity framework is trying to remove the associated `Person` row, but I don't know where I told him to do this...
I just want the `PersonBookmark` row to be deleted. Maybe I'm not understanding something obvious but as I view things the `Person` shadow property does not mean the associated `Person` should disappear with its reference owner.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just an opinion: why do you remove data instead of mark the data as deleted?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli because it's a school project and I don't have access to the database

Comment: if a person has bookmarks you can not delete person bookmarks needs to be deleted because for foreign key constraint. you can enable cascade delete in sql table that may solve for you. or you have to delete bookmarks of person first then delete person.

Comment: Here `builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey<PersonBookmark>(x => x.PersonId).HasForeignKey<Person>(x => x.PersonId);` You are telling EF that `PersonBookmark` is the **principal** of the relationship, and `Person` is the **dependent**. Deleting principal cascade deletes the dependent(s). You probably need to switch their roles.

Comment: @ToufiqAhmed I think you misunderstood my problem: the bookmarks are referencing persons, but persons don't know about the bookmarks they are in. The bookmarks should be added and deleted and the persons should not be affected by this.

Comment: @IvanStoev I was thinking about this, but if I remove I've got an exception ```System.InvalidOperationException : The relationship from 'Person' to 'PersonBookmark.Person' with foreign key properties {'PersonId' : string} cannot target the primary key {'UserId' : int, 'PersonId' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.```

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you

Comment: I'm not saying to *remove* it, but *exchange* the roles. e.g. `.HasPrincipalKey<Person>(...)..HasForeignKey<PersonBookmark>(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like entity framework is trying to remove the associated Person row, but I don't know where I told him to do this...

Right here

```cs
builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithOne()
   .HasPrincipalKey<PersonBookmark>(x => x.PersonId) // <--
   .HasForeignKey<Person>(x => x.PersonId);
```

For one-to-one relationships the generic type argument of `HasPrincipalKey` / `HasForeignKey` is used to specify who is the *principal* and who is the *dependent* in the relationship ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one)). And cascade delete works from principal to dependent direction, i.e. deleting principal cascade deletes dependent(s).

What you need here is to exchange `Person` and `PersonBookmark` roles:

```cs
builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithOne()
   .HasPrincipalKey<Person>(x => x.PersonId)
   .HasForeignKey<PersonBookmark>(x => x.PersonId);
```

Make sure to regenerate the migration and apply it to the database.

Comment: Yeah I was completely misunderstanding the foreign key aspect of the framework. Thanks!